# altair and pandas connecting two specific data details

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

My teammate and I have extracted two sets of data specifics out of two datasets from the MoMA museum.

One is to identify the gender of the artists displayed in the museum.

```
df_artists = pd.read_csv('artists.csv')
df_artists = df_artists.astype({'Artist ID': 'string'})
df_artists['Gender'] = df_artists['Gender'].str.lower()
df_artists
```

The other  to extract the time frame.

```
artists = pd.read_csv("artists.csv")

# reduce table to just Artist ID and Gender
artists = artists[ ["Artist ID", "Gender"]]

# turn the Artist IDs into strings
artists = artists.astype({"Artist ID": str})

# use Artist ID as index here, too (to allow for a join operation)
artists = artists.set_index("Artist ID")

artists



artworks = pd.read_csv("artworks.csv")

# reduce table to just Date
artworks = artworks[ ["Date"]]

# turn the Artist IDs into strings
artworks = artworks.astype({"Date": str})

# use Artist ID as index here, too (to allow for a join operation)
artworks = artworks.set_index("Date")

artworks
```

We like to combine the two, the initial idea was to visualize the data in a heat map with altair which gender was mainly displayed in the museum during that timeframe.

We're working with this data set:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/momanyc/museum-collection?select=artworks.csv

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to join the 2 dataframes, then groupby() with [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the ratio of each gender. Finally plot the heatmap with Altair:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df_artists = pd.read_csv('artists.csv')
df_artists = df_artists[['Artist ID', 'Gender']]

df_artworks = pd.read_csv('artworks.csv')
df_artworks = df_artworks[['Artist ID', 'Date']]

df = df_artists.merge(df_artworks, on='Artist ID', how='inner')
df = df.groupby('Date')['Gender']
       .value_counts(normalize=True)
       .reset_index(name='Gender_ratio')

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x = alt.X('Date:T'),
    y = alt.Y('Gender:N'),
    color = alt.Color('Gender_ratio:Q')
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help!

I've tried your suggestion out but unfortunately I get this error

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent (<ipython-input-14-79bf54eeebec>, line 12)

 File "<ipython-input-14-79bf54eeebec>", line 12
   . value_counts(normalize=True)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I tried changing the indents up but nothing much changed. Do you have an idea what may be the solution?

Comment: You could put them all on one line then: `df.groupby('Date')['Gender'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='Gender_ratio')`